# async await returning Task<List<T>> instead of List<T> on calling aync method

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

I am trying to understand the usage of async await and i studied few blog posts and now i have made a testing code but it is not working the way i am expecting it to work.

I have a method which returns List:

```
private List<Employee> GetEmployees()
{

 IList<Employee> list = new List<Employee>();
 list.Add(new Employee() { Id = 1, Age = 20, Name = "Kavin" });
 list.Add(new Employee() { Id = 2, Age = 30, Name = "Alen" });
 list.Add(new Employee() { Id = 3, Age = 20, Name = "Suresh" });
 list.Add(new Employee() { Id = 4, Age = 30, Name = "Jay" });
 list.Add(new Employee() { Id = 5, Age = 20, Name = "Nanda" });
 list.Add(new Employee() { Id = 5, Age = 20, Name = "Kavin" });
 list.Add(new Employee() { Id = 5, Age = 20, Name = "Kavin" });
 list.Add(new Employee() { Id = 1, Age = 23, Name = "Test" });

 return list;
}
```

Then i wrote my async method:

```
private async Task<List<Employee>> TestEmployeesGetAsync()
{

  var result = await Task.Run(() => GetEmployees());

  return result;
}
```

When i call this method :

```
var Result = TestEmployeesGetAsync();
```

The visual studio is telling me that it returns `Task<List<T>>` and it usage is:

```
List<Employee> result = await TestEmployeesGetAsync();
```

Why i need to put **await** on the calling method if i put `await` it gives compiler error of course because `await` should have async as well. Can somebody clear my mind how to call it so that i can get `List<T>` instead of `Task<List<T>>`

Comment: [Here's an article for you: Why must async methods return Task?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2012/11/22/why-must-async-methods-return-task.aspx), [Async and Await](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)

Comment: @JohnWoo how i can get ``List<T>`` from it

Comment: you have already shown how to get `List<T>` but you need to put `async` keyword on the method so `await` can be used.

Comment: i have made async method now what i want is to call it and get ``List<T>`` for  calling my async method  i have to make another method?

Comment: Have a look at the articles on [my `async-await` curation](http://curah.microsoft.com/45553/asyncawait-general "async-await general") to learn about `async-await` and how to use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why i need to put await on the calling method if i put await it gives
>   compiler error of course because await should have async as well.

There are a few dependencies the compiler *needs* in order to understand you're running an async method. The signal is the `async` modifier on the method declaration. Once you mark it as `async`, you can use the `await` keyword. That is why async propagates "all the way" down the call stack, as when you call one async method and need to await its result, you'll need to mark the consuming method with the async modifier.

In order to make your method work, you'll need to do the following:

```
public async Task GetEmployeesAsync()
{
   List<Employees> result = await TestEmployeesGetAsync();
}
```

As a side note, be aware that [*you should not expose async wrappers over sync methods*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx).

Comment: you mean i cannot call it without wrapping it in another method which is async?

Comment: 99% of the time, that's the way you *should* be calling your async code.

Answer (score 1):

You essentially need to wait for the result of the task returned by `TestEmployeesGetAsync`. You can do that asyncrhonously with `await` which unwraps the result for you to `List<Employee>` or you can get the result from the task with the `Result` property. However that can [cause a deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) so you need to be careful.

With `async-await` it tends to make its way up the call chain, i.e. awaiting an `async` method requires you to do that in another `async` method ( as you have found out), and awaiting that method requires you to be in yet another `async` method, and so the `async` methods spread through the code base until you reach an event handler or `Main` (which cannot be marked `async`).

This proliferation of `async` methods is not unusual, and to avoid it, you can wait for the task to complete with `Task.Wait` and `Task.Result` but these are blocking method and can cause the aforementioned deadlock. It is also an anti-pattern called sync over async and it defeats the purpose of doing the work asynchronously as you'll end up blocking waiting for it to finish anyway.

As pointed out by @BenVoigt, one exception is when you kick off multiple asynchronous requests and then  block waiting for all the tasks to complete with `Task.WaitAll`.

Comment: It doesn't defeat the purpose completely, since you can still have multiple async actions occurring during the wait.  For example, using `Task.WaitAll`.

Comment: I would expand on "it tends to make its way up the call chain". If you don't already know what that means, it would be hard to understand that sentence.