# Retrieving data from mongodb with c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Iam trying to find a good way to make a method that retrieve data from mongodb with the newest driver. All the guides I found are or old driver version or I cant make it work. I tried to make it with the tutorial at the mongodb site but it's just printing the results and I need to make a method that returns a list with my data. Can anyone show me a method that works?

```
public async Task<List<BsonDocument>> FooAsync()
{
    var Client = new MongoClient();
    var DB = Client.GetDatabase("DB");
    var collection = DB.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Users");

    var a = await collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToListAsnyc();

    return (a);
}

public static List<BsonDocument> aba()
{
    var task = FooAsync();
    var result = task.Result;

    return (result);
}
```

Comment: Have you seen http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/getting_started/quick_tour/

Comment: Yes, but I dont know how to make a method that you can call and return a list @JohnnyHK

Comment: Great, then [edit] your question to show the method that you have so far to do this and describe what's not working about it.

Comment: I edit and added my code. @JohnnyHK

Comment: Thanks. So what's not working about it? If this is in a web app that would deadlock, is that the problem?

Comment: Yes! iam getting deadlock, how can I fix it? And why it happens? @JohnnyHK

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15021304/an-async-await-example-that-causes-a-deadlock

Comment: Thank you. It's working now. @JohnnyHK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm adding a method with newest MongoDB API.

```
 public static async Task Single()
    {
        var _client = new MongoClient(CONNECTION_STRING);
        var _database = _client.GetDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
        var _collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(COLLECTION_NAME);

        var filterBuilder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
        var filter = filterBuilder.Gt("name", "gt")

        var projectBuilder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection;
        var projection = projectBuilder.Include("name").Include("lastname").Include("age").Exclude("_id");
        var count = 0;

        var results = await _collection.Find(filter).Limit
            (500).Project(projection).ToListAsync();

        foreach(var result in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            count++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("total count : " + count);

    }
```

Comment: And let's say I want to call this method and I want it to return a list my method will be like public static async Task<List<BsonDocument>> Single(). How can I call this method and get the list? @vedat

Comment: change return type of method and create a list instance. After, add documents into the list in foreach. Then return list.

Comment: for more information about using list in async method, you can look at this topic. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27309716/async-await-returning-tasklistt-instead-of-listt-on-calling-aync-method